# Python boundary tag and \& symbol not finding a matchin my string

Tags: python, regex

I was just doing

```
strn="india pp "
strn_n=re.sub('\\bp{2}\\b',' and ',strn)
print strn_n
```

My output is india and --worked as expected

But when i tried with

```
strn="india && "
strn_n=re.sub('\\b\&{2}\\b',' and ',strn)
print strn_n
```

I was expecting india and [since the && should be replaced]

But didn't find it replaced as I expected.

Can some one points me why boundary tag didn't work with `\&`  while it worked with a normal character in my first example

Comment: A word boundary matches between a word character and either a non-word-character, the start or the end of the string. `&` is a non-word-character as are the spaces surrounding it, thus there is no matching word boundary. You could use lookahead and lookbehind for this (e.g. `(?<!\S)&(?!\S)` to match only between spaces (or end/start of string)).

Comment: Well, for two `&` character, the pattern should be `(?<!\S)&&(?!\S)`, realized to late to edit my other comment.

Answer (score 2):

`\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`, so the engine fails to match `\b&\b` in your second example.

You can achieve what you want using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), by matching a `&&` that is not followed by  any non-whitespace character, and not preceeded by a one:

```
(?<!\S)&&(?!\S)
```

Note: You don't need to escape the `&` character, it doesn't have any special regex meaning, also `\b` is enough, no need for double escaping.

Comment: You might want to add, that OP should use raw strings when using regexes in python to avoid double escaping backslashes and so on.

Comment: Oh and the pattern obviously should be `(?<!\S)&&(?!\S)`, no need to copy my mistakes ;)

Answer (score 1):

`\b` will not match non-word characters as `&`, you can use `\W` instead:

```
strn_n=re.sub('\W&{2}\W',' and ',strn)
```